# Is formatting negative percentages with java DecimalFormat possible?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am trying to format percentages using the Java `DecimalFormat()` function. The format String I am using is

`'#.##%;-#%'`.

This is not giving me the negative results I would expect, e.g. -12% is showing as simply -12. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try: `'#.##%;-#\u0025'`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Still no luck. That last character is being ignored.

Comment: DecimalFormat has a `setSuffix` method that I think you can pass "%".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the percent sign in your pattern because it has a special meaning:

```
Multiply by 100 and show as percentage
```

See: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), Special Pattern Characters

Comment: I understood it had special meaning but did not realize that meant it was unusable. Good to know, thanks!